# curl -X POST -d for IPv6

Tags: curl, ryu

I'm trying to pass an ipv6 address through `curl -X POST -d`. I'm following the example with an ipv4 address.

With ipv4 it is done in the following way:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"address": "10.0.1.100/24"}' http://localhost:8080/router/0000000000000001
```

What's the syntax for sending an ipv6 address instead of the ipv4 address?
It's for a project with SDN, RYU controller and IPv6.

Thank you for the help you can give me.

Comment: The address here is inside your JSON POST body, so it's going to depend on the server that you're posting to - is that RYU? (And FYI your English is fine, except for "My english is regular" which doesn't make sense. And it would be "What is the syntax" not "How".)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Ryubook](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/Ryubook.pdf), 11.3.2, the address format look distinctly IPv4 only.

There also doesn't appear to be [router tests](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/rest_router.py) for IPv6.

Comment: Thank-you for answering.
Clearly in the Ryubook there are only examples with IPv4, but it also supports IPv6, although there is little documentation about it.

Or is there some way to assign static routes with IPv6?